# Compile FLA with all AS files

Tags: actionscript, compilation, flash, decompiling

First of all, I'm not flash expert.. still trying to figure out, however, i used a tool *(sothink SWF decompiler)* to decompile an SWF file to FLA, i first thought it will only end up with a single FLA file that has everything,
after decompiling, it extracted FLA, AS, and many different directories *(com, it, mx, org ..)*
 the problem is, Flash Pro doesn't give me the option to import those folders, it seems i need to import file by file with the way they sorted which is really painful, in fact.. i don't know how, after searching for a while i think they're libraries, i guess some of those libraries are default in flash pro and are already in there, and some others as i noticed are file-related

I wonder if there's some way to import all the decompiled contents .. edit actionscript and save it back to an SWF file ?

Comment: have you tried compiling the generated .fla ? it should use a document class which uses the rest of the classes. the code will be messy and variable names won't help, so you'd need to start following variables around and giving them a meaningful name, fix errors, etc. goodluck

Comment: In your main FLA you can go into publish settings > actionscript settings and there you can set all the classpaths. These are the paths where the FLA should look for .as classes when compiling.

Comment: since you mentioned that it contains an MX folder, it probably wasnt created by Flash Pro, it was probably created by Flash Builder, targeting Flex framework.